# Dependencia Circular en Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi

Estoy generando unos informes en Power BI usando DAX, y me he topado con un error al cual no le encuentro el origen. El error es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver, consiste en una serie de condicionales anidados. En un principio no estoy modificando nada que use posteriormente. Dejo aquí el código:

```
    TM Agente = 

if((SECOND([TM Admin]) + SECOND([TM Conver])) >= 60; 

  if(((MINUTE([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver])) + 1) >= 60;
  TIME((Hour([TM Admin]) + Hour([TM Conver])) + 1; (Minute([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver])) - 59;(Second([TM Admin]) + Second([TM Conver]))  - 60); 

   if((Minute([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver])) >= 60;
  TIME((Hour([TM Admin]) + Hour([TM Conver]))  + 1; (Minute([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver])) - 60; (Second([TM Admin]) + Second([TM Conver])) - 60);
  TIME(Hour([TM Admin]) + Hour([TM Conver]); Minute([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver]) + 1;(Second([TM Admin]) + Second([TM Conver])) - 60))); 

  TIME(Hour([TM Admin]) + Hour([TM Conver]); Minute([TM Admin]) + Minute([TM Conver]); Second([TM Admin]) + Second([TM Conver])))
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar o echar un poco de luz sobre el asunto, por favor?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ya está resuelto.

El problema era que estaba haciendo referencia a Medidas en lugar de a Columnas calculadas.

Comment: Para que otros puedan guiarse mejor por tu respuesta, podrías detallar brevemente qué cambiaste?